# Why does this statement turn out to be false if this vector space is not finite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a  fnite-dimensional vector space, and let T : V → V be a linear transformation. **If T is surjective, then T is an isomorphism.**

Show that the top statement may be false if V is not finite-dimensional.

I was thinking that if it not finite dimensional, then there are not restrictions on the transformation, and for T to be an isomorphism both of the vector spaces have to have the same dimension. I'm not sure if this constitutes as a proof.

Comment: You need to construct an explicit counterexample to disprove that statement for infinite dimensional spaces. What you have is not a proof.

Comment: Thinking about linear maps as maps on the bases, this is the same as saying that there is surjective, but non-injective map $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. You believe in this statement, don't you? And I am sure, you can give an example.

Answer (score 3):

This is a 'non-constructed', but rather natural example from analysis:

The derivation on $C^1(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ - the space of differentiable real functions - is surjective. This is what the fundamental theorem tells you. But it is not injective, since constants are mapped to zero.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite concrete example is the left shift operator: If your space $V$ is all real valued sequences, consider the map taking the sequence taking $(a_1,a_2\cdots)$ to $(a_2,a_3\cdots)$. This is surjective because for any $(b_1,b_2\cdots )\in V$, this map takes $(0,b_1,b_2\cdots)$ to it. It is not injective because $(1,0,0\cdots)$ and $(0,0,\cdots)$ both map to $(0,0,\cdots)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{v_i \mid i \in I\}$ be an infinite basis of your infinite-dimensional vector space $V$. Pick a countable subset $\{v_{i_n} \mid n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ of the basis vectors. Consider the unique linear transformation $T : V \to V$ determined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
T(v_{i_1}) &= v_{i_1} \\
T(v_{i_{n+1}}) &= v_{i_n} &&\text{for $n \geq 1$,}\\
T(v_i) &= v_i &&\text{if $i \neq i_n$ for any $n$.}
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $T$ is surjective, but not injective.